# Application insights - Create a pie chart out of customMeasurements

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, ms-app-analytics

I create a custom event whenever a job is processed and use a customMeasurement for every file type I can process.

```
tc.TrackEvent("File processed",
                metrics: new Dictionary<string, double>{
                  
                    { "HTML", FileType == 0 ? 1 : 0 },
                    { "Excel", FileType == 1 ? 1 : 0},
                    { "CSV", FileType == 2 ? 1 : 0},
                    { "XML" , FileType == 3 ? 1 : 0},
                    ...
```

I want to create a Log query and show it as a pie chart in my dashboard.

I have reached so far to the query:

```
customEvents
| project csv=todouble(customMeasurements['CSV']), excel = todouble(customMeasurements['Excel']), html = todouble(customMeasurements['HTML']), xml = todouble(customMeasurements['XML'])
| summarize sum(csv),  sum(excel),  sum(html),  sum(xml)
```

And this generates the following table:

```
sum_csv | sum_excel | sum_html | sum_xml
      3 |       230 |      100 |      45
```

But I need to create a table with the file type summaries and the file type title, such as:

```
File type | Count
HTML      |  100
XML       |   45
Excel     |  230
CSV       |    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mvexpand bagexpansion=array` you can access the columns by using an index. That allows you to perform grouping. So try this:

```
customEvents
| mvexpand bagexpansion=array customMeasurements
| summarize Count = sum(toint(customMeasurements[1])) by FileType = tostring(customMeasurements[0]) 
| where FileType in ('XML','HTML','Excel','CSV')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This query language is quite unknown to me, are there any books or any other resources to learn it?

Comment: Sure, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ and https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/kusto-query-language-kql-from-scratch and https://github.com/rod-trent/MustLearnKQL